# if $\phi : X \rightarrow X/N$ is onto implies $\operatorname{ker} \phi =N$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $\phi : X \rightarrow X/N$ is a surjective homomorphism does it imply that $\operatorname{ker} \phi =N$ ? where $N$ is a normal subgroup of $X$.

Comment: Should "subjective" = **surjective** ?

Comment: yes! :-) sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Think about the Klein four-group.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you have a normal subgroup which is not characteristic, you have a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, $\operatorname{ker}(\phi)$ is not necessarily isomorphic to $N$. For instance, let $Z_i=\mathbb Z_2$ for all $i\in\mathbb N$. Then define $G=\bigoplus_{i\in\mathbb N} Z_i$. Then $G/Z_1\cong G$, and a isomorphism $\phi$ obviously has null kernel.

Comment: @Serkan Good point. See my edit for my plan B.

Comment: What is $\phi((1, 0, 0, \ldots))$?

Comment: @user66345 Firstly, let's establish that $+$ is the operation of $G$. Let $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}$ be a bijection. If $x_n$ generates the subgroup corresponding to $Z_n$, then define $\phi(x_n)=\langle x_{f(n)}+\mathbb N\rangle$. Then $\phi: G\to G/Z_1$ is an isomorphism.